# Accumulation Points for $S = \{(-1)^n + \frac1n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I was recently asked to find the accumulation points of the set $$S = \{(-1)^n + \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

I answered that the accumulation points are $\{-1,1\}$, because despite the fact that $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, we can still use $\frac{1}{n}$ to find an element arbitrarily close to either $1$ or $-1$, i.e. to show that there is an element in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $1$ or $-1$. (No proof was required for this question --- this is my intuition.)

Am I right at all?

Comment: You are right except that $\frac1n$ does *not* diverge

Comment: But I thought that the Harmonic Series diverges? (Or does the sequence converge to zero, but the sum of the sequence does not converge?) What's going on here?

Comment: You don't have a harmonic SERIES; you have a harmonic SEQUENCE.

Comment: Right. Thanks.   $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's denote
$$a_n=(-1)^n+\frac{1}{n}$$
then the subsequence $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ are convergent to $1$ and $-1$ respectively then $1$ and $-1$ are two accumulation points. There's not other accumulation point since any convergent subsequence of $((-1)^n)$ has either $1$ or $-1$ as limit.

Comment: Nice work, Sami!